# Drop down list set to 1 if check box is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a website that lets user create billing cycles and I want it so if they click on the check box then the drop down list has to be equal to or greater than 1. Here is the code for the check box and the code for the drop down list.

```
<tr>
  <td>Set As A Recurring Fee Every (leave blank for a one-time charge)<br/>
    <select name="FrequencyDuration" style="width:50px; background: url('images/subfield_50.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;">
      <option value=""></option>
    <cfloop from="1" to="60" step="1" index="i">
      <option value="#i#">#i#</option>
    </cfloop>
    <cfif #session.cid# eq '15351' or #session.pid# eq 'f39ec354'><option value="1" SELECTED>1</option></cfif>
    </select>
    <select name="FrequencyUnit" style="width:100px; background:url('images/subfield_100.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;">
      <option value="d">Day(s)</option>
      <option value="ww">Week(s)</option>
      <option value="m">Month(s)</option>
      <option value="q">Quarter(s)</option>
      <option value="yyyy">Year(s)</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td colspan="2" align="right">
     <span style="position:relative; top:10px;">Do Not Submit Fee; Only Establish Recurring Fee 
       <input type="Checkbox" name=" Only" value="1">
     </span> 
     <input class="standardButtonRight button" id="submitFeesbtn"  type="submit" value="Submit Fee" style="border:0px;"></input>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</cfoutput>
</div>
```

Now here is where the form is validated:

```
//Form Validation
$('#submitFees').validate({
  wrapper: "span",
  position: "bottom",
  messageClass: "error",
  debug:true
});

var frm = $('#submitFees');
$('#submitFeesbtn').click(function(){
  if($('#submitFees').valid()) {
    $.ajax({
      type: frm.attr('method'),
      url: frm.attr('action'),
      data: frm.serialize(),
      success: function (data) {
        $('div#clientFees').html(data).hide().fadeIn(500);
      }    
    });
  }
  return false;
});
```

Would this work and I can not figure out how to implement it.

```
   if($("# Only").prop('checked')){
        return true;
    } else {
        alert('Please set the recuuring fee');
    }
```

Comment: Please include a demo fiddle - [link](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: `The drop down list has to equal to or greater than 1 `?? Be more specific ....

Comment: i dont see you trying to do anything with the checkbox or select box in your js code

Comment: Right now if #session.cid# eq '15351' or #session.pid# eq 'f39ec354' you will have two option value = 1

Comment: the second part of the javascript has the check box function in it